# How to load multiple sqlite driver versions on a single java server?

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, jdbc

### The Problem

Hi, I'm trying to implement sqlite in a server plugin, but I'd like to use a different version than is provided with the server - is this possible?

I've set up sqlite in my project, and it works perfectly for most data types, however because of the server's sqlite version, I'm unable to write binary arrays to my database. The server ships with 3.7.2, however this version doesn't support **Statement#setBinaryStream**, so I'd like to use 3.8.11.2 in my project.

I'm unable to change the server's sqlite version, and it is unlikely that this version will be changed any time soon, so my solution was to try and include a different sqlite version in my project jar, and use that. I'm a big fan of sqlite, so if possible, I'd like to be able to use it.

### What I've Tried

I have tried the following:

1. Use the maven shade plugin to include the **sqlite-jdbc** library with my project, relocating **org.sqlite** to **me.Fupery.shaded.sqlite**
2. Register my relocated driver with the **java.sql.DriverManager** singleton:

   ```
   Driver driver = ((Driver) Class.forName("me.Fupery.shaded.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance());
   DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
   ```
3. Get the connection as usual

   ```
   Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbFileURL);
   ```

But no luck! The lib is correctly included in my jar, and the code to register the driver (above) runs without exceptions, however when I try to write a byte stream, it throws an AbstractMethodError as usual (indicating it's using the old version, not the one I loaded).

Is there a way to specify which driver to use when getting a connection? I looked through the DriverManager and Driver methods but couldn't find anything I could use.

### Alternative Methods

Alternatively, is there another method I can use to write a blob to a database in the server's provided sqlite version (3.7.2)? I tried **Statement#setBytes** before **Statement#setBinaryStream**, but I didn't have any luck - no exceptions are thrown, but the column I set the byte to is empty.

A test I wrote [here](https://gist.github.com/Fupery/822296dc3731836cd6626965fbaf09e7) returns without errors, but when I check the database afterwards, the "test" column is empty every time (other data types work fine):

```
$ SELECT * FROM test_table;
test1|
test2|                           
test3|
```

Comment: *"Alternatively, is there another method I can use [with] ... the server's provided sqlite version (3.7.2)?"* - org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2 can definitely use `setBytes` to write to a SQLite BLOB column. Confirmed with test code [here](http://pastebin.com/L6jz0trm) and [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ld6h3.png) of result.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson, this indeed works! I realised I was being silly and wrote an empty byte array in my test, meaning no result showed up when I queried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to use the Statement#setBytes method to write to a blob instead in 3.7.2, now that I've been able to get this to work correctly. It's is a simpler and tidier solution, and works just as well.